# How to find a fixed interval of dates between several months in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I want to find a select set of dates between several months of several years, for example I want all the dates between (15/01/2018 to 14/02/2018) and (15/02/2018 to 14/03/2018) and so on until (15/11/2020 to 14/12/2020).

My data looks like

```py
Date        State code    Profit
01-01-2018     1           268
02-01-2018     2           230
   ...        ...          ...
   ...        ...          ...
   ...        ...          ...
31-12-2020     1           740
```

I want to work with Data corresponding to dates 15/MM/YYYY and 14/MM/YYYY and for that I've tried

```py
pd.date_range(start='15/01/2018',end='14/01/2018',period=30)

pd.date_range(start='15/01/2018',end='14/01/2018',freq=30D)
```

This doesn't help as it doesn't generate the desired date set.

I've tried using a for loop as well:

```py
for i in range(1,13):
   print(pd.date_range(start='15/'+str(i)+'/2018',end='14/'+str(i+1)+'/2018')
```

but it gives the error

```py
ValueError: could not convert string to Timestamp
```

Please guide as to how the desired result be achieved.

Comment: @ddejohn yeah, but again how will the month be updated in rolling window query, it doesn't make sense if I have to write the set of date for every monthly interval.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your desired output is, but let's assume you're trying to do a grouby on the said custom date ranges. This can be done with combining [cutting](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) the dataframe on the desired dates with [grouping](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) the intervals. First, you'll need to have a list of dates to cut on, let's say every date in the `Date` column of which the day equals `14`: `df['Date'][lambda x: x.dt.day==14])`. Then feed this to `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Date'], df['Date'][lambda x: x.dt.day==14]))
```

Comment: Hey, My desired output is the list of dates between 15th of month M and 14th of month M+1.

Comment: Ok, then this would do `df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Date'], df['Date'][lambda x: x.dt.day==14]))['Date'].apply(list).to_list()`